# MultiBinding using DisplayMemeberBinding for MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, menuitem

I have the following XAML

```
<MenuItem Header="_Recent Studies"
            Height="22" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding FullFileName}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```

Which displayed my recent files like

[image: Recents]

However, I want to display the item number of the `MenuItem` next to the file name like VS2012 does.

> 1. FileNameA.f
> 2. FileNameB.x
> 3. FileNameC.j

etc. To do this I decided to use a converter Where if I were just getting the number without the file name I could do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/662232/626442). But I want to incorporate this with multi-binding so I can write something like

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}. {1}">
    <Binding Path="??"/> 
    <Binding Path="FullFileName"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

I don't know what to write in the above. **How can I prefix my files names with the number that the file is in the list *without* adding an index property to my `FullFileName`s which would make things more complex?**

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit. This is how I use the below answer in my code

```
<MenuItem Header="_FILE">
    ...
    <MenuItem Header="_Recent Studies" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}" 
              AlternationCount="{Binding RecentFiles.Count}" 
              HeaderTemplate="{x:Null}">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" 
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
                   <Setter.Value>
                      <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}. {1}">
                                  <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" 
                                           RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}" 
                                           Converter="{StaticResource IntPlusNConverter}"/>
                                  <Binding Path="FullFileName"/>
                               </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                         </TextBlock>
                      </DataTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
    </MenuItem>
    <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="E_xit" 
                  Height="22"
                  Icon="{Binding Source={StaticResource Close}, 
                                 Converter={StaticResource drawingBrushToImageConverter}}"
                  Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
</MenuItem>
```

This works! However, all my XAML for the FILE `MenuItem` block is being highlighted and I get a compile-time error (the code runs and works though!), saying

> An object of the type "System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Style".

**Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?**

Thanks for your time.

---

**RESULT!**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with `AlternationIndex` like in this answer

[Finding Listbox Index of ListBoxItem (ItemsTemplate to specify Visual COntent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392835/finding-listbox-index-of-listboxitem-itemstemplate-to-specify-visual-content/18393104#18393104)

You may have to override the `HeaderTemplate` because the `StringFormat` may not work correctly because `Header` is an `object` not a `string`

Example:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Recent Studies"  ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}" AlternationCount="{Binding RecentFiles.Count}" HeaderTemplate="{x:Null}">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}. {1}">
                                   <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}" />
                                   <Binding Path="FullFileName"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Man, you really know WPF! My aim is to become all powerful, just like you 'Master'...

Comment: Hi mate, this solution will clearly work, but I am getting `an object of the type "system.windows.staticresourceextension" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "system.windows.style".` when I include the style in the code at the position I have it. I have moved the style to a `ResourceDictionary` and tried to give the `Style` and `x:Key="..."` and use that in the `MainWindow` but this is not working can you advise please?

Comment: can you show me how you use the style in the MainWindow, It seems to work find anywhere I move this style

Comment: I copied your code and it seems to work fine (except the converters I don't have), what VisualStudio version are you using, I can try on that

Comment: VS2012. Not sure why it is putting this error out as the code works fine and shows exactly what I want. Perhaps I will ask another question about this... Is there an easy way to move the Style in to a `ResourceDictionary` without breaking the `AlternatingCount`?

Comment: Asked another question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18846661/626442. thanks again for your time...

Comment: for the `AlternationCount` you should be able to bind back to the `MenuItem` `Items.Count` if you put it in a Style, `AlternationCount="{Binding Path=Items.Count, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`