# Odd XAML Error: '"System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension" cannot be applied'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, menuitem

I have the following XAML to provide a recent document menu like VS2012's FILE > Recent Documents menu

```
<MenuItem Header="_FILE">
    ...
    <MenuItem Header="_Recent Studies" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}" 
              AlternationCount="{Binding RecentFiles.Count}" 
              HeaderTemplate="{x:Null}">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" 
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
                   <Setter.Value>
                      <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}. {1}">
                                  <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" 
                                           RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                                           AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}"/>
                                  <Binding Path="FullFileName"/>
                               </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                         </TextBlock>
                      </DataTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
    </MenuItem>
    <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="E_xit" 
                  Height="22"
                  Icon="{Binding Source={StaticResource Close}, 
                                 Converter={StaticResource drawingBrushToImageConverter}}"
                  Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
</MenuItem>
```

This works! However, all my XAML for the FILE `MenuItem` block is being highlighted and I get a compile-time error (the code runs and works though!), saying

> An object of the type "System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Style".

I am using .NET4.5 and VS2012. **Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution, maybe even a VS restart, I can't replicate this error in VS2013, VS2012, VS2010

Comment: Yes, I have. You have mentioned using a `ResourceDictionary` that references the items themselves I am not sure how this would work but think this could solve the problem?

Comment: If I comment out the entire menu item the error disappears. If I just comment out all of the `</MenuItem.Resources>
` code the error persists...

Comment: How can I move the `MenuItem.Resources` to a resource dictionary without effecting the ability to bind to the `RecentFiles` object?

Comment: Do you have another `MenuItem` Style somewhere, The one being used by `BasedOn`

Comment: Ah, yes, I am using MahAppsMetro resources which I believe has a `MenuItem` override/template that I am using... I will change the based on property and see if that helps.

Comment: I have moved the code for the `MenuItem.Resources` to the parent <MenuItem> and this removes the error, however I loose the bindings to the RecentFiles. I will try the based on approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

You should be able to move the `Style` to any `ResourceDictionary` and it should still work, you will just have to apply it to the Items inside the `MenuItem` using `ItemContainerStyle`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}. {1}">
                                <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}"/>
                                <Binding Path="FullFileName"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Menu VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_FILE" >
            <MenuItem Header="_Recent Studies" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}"
                      AlternationCount="{Binding RecentFiles.Count}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyMenuStyle}" />
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="E_xit" Height="22" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Great. Error is gone, but my base metro style for the drop down recent list now does not work and neither does my converter. Again I am sorry bother you and will provide some rep when I can... Thanks again...

Comment: opps I removed the converter and BasedOn, if you add them back it should work

Comment: Shiiiii*, I hadn't even looked. Sorry about that - stupid AGAIN!

Comment: Lovely jubbley! See edit for the beautiful results! Thanks again man - you are a massive help and you an @Marc have really enabled me to break the back of WPF and MVVM so thank you (I clearly still have a way to go though!).